# Forward selector to multiple objects in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to re-implement a class in Swift, but have run into problems. My pattern is to have a single object which forwards methods in a protocol to multiple other objects.

I have a protocol which looks like:

```
@protocol AnalyticsProvider {
@optional

    - (void)showHomePage;
    - (void)selectedMenuItem:(NSString *)item;

    // ...
    // 100 or so more methods :sigh:
    // ...

@end
```

The idea being that I can call `showHomePage` on a singleton and have it forwarded to multiple objects who will each do their own thing with that message.

I would configure the singleton on startup like this:

```
[AppAnalytics sharedAnalytics] setProviders:@[ myFlurryProvider, myOmnitureProvider] ];
```

where myFlurryProvider and myOmnitureProvider are real implementers of the `AnalyticsProvider` protocol.
And then in my view controllers I would have lines like this:

```
[[AppAnalytics sharedAnalytics] showHomePage];
```

This should send homepage analytics events to both Flurry and Adobe Omniture, for example. This works because the `AppAnalytics` class implements the `AnalyticsProvider` protocol *but doesn't actually contain code for any of the methods*.

By implementing `forwardInvocation:` in `AppAnalytics` I can forward the methods to each provider i.e.

```
- (void)forwardImplementation:(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    for provider in providers
        if ([provider respondsToSelector:invocation.selector])
            [invocation performWithTarget:provider]
}
```

By not implementing any of the methods in my `AppAnalytics` singleton the calls are automagically passed into `forwardImplementation:` as an `NSInvocation`, but because `AppAnalytics` conforms to the protocol I get compiler safety at the point of calling. win win. It's fairly important I don't have to actually implement any methods in AppAnalytics because there are 100s of them and I don't want that much repeated code!

Any ideas on a good way to implement this in Swift, given that `NSInvocation` is forbidden!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure which class had the forwardImplementation method nor where the services list comes from but it seems that providing default implementations (that do nothing) for each method in your protocol would achieve the type safety without requiring the methods to actually be implemented in any of the classes that comply to the protocol.

Comment: It would, but there are over 100 methods in the protocol (it's analytics for a fairly large app) so I'd like to avoid this if possible! The services list is created in the app delegate on startup. The forwardInvocation is in the singleton, and it works because the singleton doesn't implement _any_ of the protocol methods so they all end up in that one place :)

Comment: PS I've edited my question to make it a bit clearer (I hope) based on your answer :)